# Why the code below for creating 20 buttons one under the other in relative layout causes the app to stop

Tags: java, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create 20 buttons one under the previously created one in relative layout. The code I use is as follows.

```
ViewGroup layoutListe = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_Liste);
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i + 1);
        btn.setText("buton" + (i+1));

        layoutListe.addView(btn);

        switch (i){
            case 0:   //the first one will be placed to its default place.
                break;
            default:  //the rest of 19 buttons will be placed under the previous one.
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (i));
                layoutListe.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, it stops immediately with the error below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:186)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
```

Any idea to fix this.

I am not using linearLayout because I am planning to add some more buttons to the right of them in the near future. But I could not achive the first part of the task. :)

When I run the code in debug mode, I see that it finishes all 20 loops without any error. After finisihing the for loop, I press F9 to continue and get the error.

Comment: I'm not Android dev so I have to guess but it seems the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` you want to use is not compatible to `layoutListe` (which seems to expect `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`). A wild guess here: are there any generics you ignored and used raw types instead?

Comment: When I remove the whole switch block from the code, it work. But of course all buttons are at the same place, I mean all of them are top of each other as expected.

Comment: Sure, the switch block contains the error, i.e. you're using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` there. Thus removing it also removes the exception but as you said, that's not the way to solve such a problem. You need to think about the actual cause and that's where my guess comes in: you're probably using the wrong layout params object or applying it to the wrong element. That's what you should look into.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code working like a charm...

```
for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i + 1);
        btn.setText("buton " + (i+1));
        
        switch (i){
            case 0:  //The first one stays at its default place
                break;
            default:  //The others goes to the bottom of the previous ones.
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (i));
                //relativeLayout_Liste.setLayoutParams(params);
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;
        }

        relativeLayout_Liste.addView(btn);
    }
```